# Incrementing Class, need to stop and start from beginning

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script that gives a table an incrementing class, however, I have a multiple tables that are identicle that need to have the same class applied. CUrrently at the end of one table, it just continues to increment the class.

current: class =: 1,2,3,4,5,6[end of table]7,8,9,10,11,12

what i'm looking for: class =: 1,2,3,4,5,6[end of table]1,2,3,4,5,6

This is my script:

```
<script>
    var j = 1;
$("table.mobile_table tr").each(function(){
   $(this).attr("class", j++); // Give rows incrementing class
});
</script>
```

Comment: loop through each table, using a separate `j` var for each. Now on to the real question... Why are you doing this? I can't think of a single case where this would be the appropriate way of solving the problem (using enumerated classes)...

Comment: Dynmaic tables, will have no idea how many rows or tables there may be. This is part of making my own mobile friendly tables similar to jquery reflow tables.

Comment: Right that's explained in your question, but what are the enumerated classes for? Why can't you just use the index of the table row as the enumeration?

Comment: well, haha, its a Friday afternoon and my brain is fried. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
<script>

$("table.mobile_table").each(function(){
   var j = 1;
   var currentTable = $(this);
   currentTable.find("tr").each(function(){
      $(this).attr("class", j++);
   });

});
</script>
```

Comment: `currentTable.find("tr").attr("class", function(){return j++;})` or even `currentTable.find("tr").attr("class", function(i){return i+1;})`

Comment: indeed that is much better

Answer (score 2):

You need to reset the `j` variable for each table. You could also do.

```
$("table.mobile_table tr").addClass(function(){
    return ($(this).closest('.mobile_table tr').index(this) + 1);
});
```

Or

```
$("table.mobile_table").each(function(){
   $(this).find('tr').addClass(function(i){
          return i+1;
   });
});
```